# State value null inside a function only on the first invocation

Tags: reactjs

I am making a simple checkout page but I've been stuck on this small issue. I'm getting discount percentage in 'handleDiscount' from backend and console.log shows updated value, it even renders in UI but in 'handleTickets' function 'discountPercent' is null (only in the first try after that it runs the if block). What am I doing wrong here?

```
const Checkout = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuthContext();
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState("");
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState("1");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [discountCode,setDiscountCode] = useState("");
  const [totalDiscount,setTotalDiscount] = useState("");
  const [discountPercent,setDiscountPercent] = useState(null);
  const [disableDiscount,setDisableDiscount] = useState(false);
  const [netAmount,setNetAmount] = useState("");


  console.log("discount %", discountPercent);
 
  const handleTickets = (value) => {
    setTickets(value);
    var fee = result?.fee > 0 ? result?.fee : 0;
    let total = parseFloat(result?.price) + parseFloat(fee);
    total = total * parseFloat(value);
    setTotalPrice(total);

    console.log(discountPercent) //<==== shows null only on first try, after that it works correctly

    if(discountPercent){
      let discount = (total * discountPercent) / 100;
      setTotalDiscount(discount);
      setNetAmount(total - discount);
    }
  };

  const handleDiscount = async () => {
    try{
      const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/discount`,
      {
        amount: totalPrice,
        discount_code: discountCode,
      });
      if(res.data.valid){
        setTotalDiscount(res.data.discount_amount);
        setDiscountPercent(res.data.discount_percentage);
        setDisableDiscount(true)
      }
      else{
        alert('Invalid discount code');
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log("e",error.response.data)
    }
  }

 
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/singleproduct/${key}`)
      .then((response) => {
        0;
        setResult(response.data.product);
        let total =
          parseFloat(response.data.product.price) +
          parseFloat(response.data.product.fee);
        setTotalPrice(total);
        setNetAmount(total);
        setPrice(response.data.product.price);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);


return (
      <>
              {discountPercent}  <== updates correctly here
              <Card mode="outlined">
                <Card.Content>
                      <Text>Total Price: </Text>
                      <Text> ${totalPrice} </Text>
                
                      <Text> Discount: </Text>
                      <Text> ${totalDiscount} </Text>

                      <Text> Net Total: </Text>
                      <Text> {netAmount ? `$${netAmount}` : ''} </Text>
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>
            ) 

              <DropDown
                label={"Total Tickets"}
                mode={"outlined"}
                value={tickets}
                setValue={handleTickets}
                list={ticketList}
              />
          
              <div>
                <TextInput 
                disabled={disableDiscount}
                onChange={(v) => setDiscountCode(v.currentTarget.value)}
                placeholder="Enter discount code (if any)"
                />
                <Button 
                disabled={disableDiscount || !discountCode}
                onClick={handleDiscount} mode="contained"
                >
                <Icon name="arrow-right"/>
                </Button>
              </div>
            
      </>

  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

I tried wrapping the handleTickets function in a useCallback but that didn't work.

```
 const handleTickets = useCallback((value) => {
    setTickets(value);
    var fee = result?.fee > 0 ? result?.fee : 0;
    let total = parseFloat(result?.price) + parseFloat(fee);
    total = total * parseFloat(value);
    setTotalPrice(total);

    console.log(discountPercent) //<==== shows null only on first try, after that it works correctly

    if(discountPercent){
      let discount = (total * discountPercent) / 100;
      setTotalDiscount(discount);
      setNetAmount(total - discount);
    }
  },[discountPercent,result?.fee,result?.price]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because state updates are asynchronous ([docs reference](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

This could be the case since it updates correctly in the UI but doesn't update correctly/immediately in the first run of the `handleTickets()` call.

To fix this, you can use the [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) hook. But keep in mind that it doesn't update the state, but that should be fine in your code since you update other states in the same function call, which should re-render the UI.

---

Lastly, with the current elements, a user may trigger `handleTickets()` before `handleDiscount()`, in which `discountPercent` should be `null` since it hasn't been changed yet.